# Reply all excluding email MacroButton

Tags: vba, outlook, reply

Trying to write a macro for usual reply all option but I want to exclude 1 specific addressee. I've been trying to type myself, but I've got an error "Object Required". I've searched through the internet and found code for default option (public sub). I need it to be assigned to the separate button

```
  Dim oReply As MailItem
  Set oReply = oItem.ReplyAll
  Dim recips  As Outlook.Recipients
  Dim i As Long
 Set recips = oReply.Recipients
 For i = recips.Count To 1 Step -1
  If LCase(recips.Item(i).Address) = "alias@slipstick.com" Then
 recips.Remove i
 End If
 Next

 oReply.Display


 Set oItem = Nothing
 End Sub
```

Comment: Has oItem been Set?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to assign the `oItem` in the code first. For example, for the current inspector window you can use the following code:

```
Public Sub Test()
 Dim inspector as Outlook.Inspector

 Set inspector = Application.ActiveInspector()
 Set oItem = inspector.CurrentItem

 Dim oReply As MailItem
 Set oReply = oItem.ReplyAll
 Dim recips  As Outlook.Recipients
 Dim i As Long
 Set recips = oReply.Recipients
 For i = recips.Count To 1 Step -1
  If LCase(recips.Item(i).Address) = "alias@slipstick.com" Then
   recips.Remove i
  End If
 Next
 oReply.Save
 oReply.Display
 Set oItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

In case of explorer's selection you need to use the [Selection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/explorer-selection-property-outlook) property of the Explorer class which returns a `Selection` object that contains the item or items that are selected in the explorer window.

Comment: I need it to be done by hitting the button to which macro is assigned